# In "fieri del efecto", what does "fieri" mean?

Tags: definiciones, latinismo

The sentence is this one:

> Hay que tener presente aquí que el infinito de que se trata en las vías es un infinito metafísico(...) y no un infinito matemático(...) ni físico, en el que las causas son unívocas y explican, en todo caso, el **fieri del efecto**.

I've also seen the expression 'fieri' sometimes counterposed to 'facto', like in the article [La iglesia católica: La esencia del matrimonio](http://www.publiboda.com/esencia/index.html). I've tried searching the Spanish dictionary but I got no hits. The Italian gave me meanings like 'proud' and others similar, but they don't seem to fit well in this sentence.

Comment: It's Latin from the expression *in fieri* which means (more or less) "in the making".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`In fieri`: Locución latina que se emplea para designar aquello que está por hacer. Procede del verbo *fio* que significa *convertirse*. Esta locución se emplea para expresar que algo está

> en proceso, pendiente.

[Referencia de glosario jurídico (Letra i)](http://www.eumed.net/diccionario/jaor/GLOSARIO%20JURIDICO%20LATINO%20LETRA%20I.htm)

Comment: It's not my answer guys, is **community wiki**. As far as I know these can be voted and accepted (so users can show they agree with the answer, and they are correct and useful, as with any other answers) but nobody gets points for those votes (they "belong" to the site, not to one user). Community wiki answers can be improved by any user. I posted the answer this way because I wanted the question to have a proper answer but I wasn't going to take credit for something @guifa already answered correctly in his comment.